# Redirect to registration and not login page during UberCart checkout in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, authentication, registration, ubercart

Currently if a user is not logged in, they are redirected to the "login page" when checking out in UberCart. I need them to rather be redirected to the "registration" page.

In other words:

```
Go here: user/register
NOT here: user
```

The key here is to get it to work with UberCart. I know you can use login toboggan and other tricks to do it normally, but I can't get it to work with UberCart?

**UPDATE**

I still don't have a decent solution so I added bounty for this. Currently, if you have "anonymous checkout" disabled, ubertcart automatically add these messages:

1. You must login before you can proceed to checkout.
2. If you do not have an account yet, you should register now.

This is also a problem in that it doesn't make sense showing them if you go to the user page. So even my hard hack of forwarding the user to /user/register whenever it encounters "user?destination=cart/checkout" and the user is not logged, to forward them to "user/register?destination=cart/checkout" does not work that well.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2**

This is where the magic happens: line 94, uc_cart.pages.inc

```
// Send anonymous users to login page when anonymous checkout is disabled.
if (!$user->uid && !variable_get('uc_checkout_anonymous', TRUE)) {
    drupal_set_message(t('You must login before you can proceed to checkout.'));
    if (variable_get('user_register', 1) != 0) {
    drupal_set_message(t('If you do not have an account yet, you should <a href="!url">register now</a>.', array('!url' => url('user/register', array('query' => drupal_get_destination())))));
  }
  drupal_goto('user', array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));
}
```

So, basically I need a way to override that behaviour? (i.e. without hacking core?)

Comment: I would love to hear if and how you solved this

Comment: I used rules and token module as suggested on one site, but on another site, I added a module that does that checks for me. Basically, it just has a "init" hook that checks if it is the registration path and if it is, it does the redirect for me. It worked well in the one case. Inbox me if you want more info.

Comment: ps. I added an update as to why my solution is not ideal. I know my solution is a hack.

Comment: pps. With logintoboggan I sort of got a better solution going, as now the login and registration forms are "on the same page". They are still in tabs, so the next step is to override logintoboggan theme functions in order to change the tabs into two columns that will fit in with my bootstrap theme.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the rules and token module.  You will create a rule when a user logs in to redirect to the the TOKEN.  Make sure you enable the token actions module as well.

Comment: This is not the right answer. Read the entire question.

Comment: If it's been over almost 4 years and you haven't figured it out yet I'm guessing you may never.  I've since moved on to frameworks based on python where you don't have to deal with garbage like this.  If drupal ain't cutting the mustard I suggest thinking of that as an option.